# Adding Namespace in the xml root tag explicitly WCF

Tags: xml, wcf, soapui

I  have created a WCF service and I am using SOAPUI for sending SOAP requests.

Below is the Request xml  that tool is generating from  my C# models :

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <w3:PerformScan>
            <w3:request>
                <w3:SearchConfiguration>
                    <w3:ConfidenceThreshold>?</w3:ConfidenceThreshold>
                    <w3:ResultConfiguration></w3:ResultConfiguration>
                    <w3:ScanRequest xsi:type="w3:CustomerRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <w3:CustomerId>?</w3:CustomerId>
                        <w3:CustomerName>?</w3:CustomerName>
                    </w3:ScanRequest>
                </w3:SearchConfiguration>
            </w3:request>
        </w3:PerformScan>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But to make it workable I need to modify the request xml. Below is the modified and working xml :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <w3:PerformScan xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/">
            <w3:request>
                <w3:SearchConfiguration>
                    <w3:ConfidenceThreshold>?</w3:ConfidenceThreshold>
                    <w3:ResultConfiguration></w3:ResultConfiguration>
                    <w3:ScanRequest xsi:type="w3:CustomerRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <w3:CustomerId>?</w3:CustomerId>
                        <w3:CustomerName>?</w3:CustomerName>
                    </w3:ScanRequest>
                </w3:SearchConfiguration>
            </w3:request>
        </w3:PerformScan>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How can I force my c# models  or what to do  to make `xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/"` in `PerformScan` node autopopulated while generating from tool.

Comment: Both are same, no difference. No need to define the same namespace twice.

Comment: Yes Both are identical.  But i need to Add xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/" either in PerformScan or in request node to make it workable otherwise it giving error  :     The attribute 'type' has an invalid value 'w3:CustomerRequest' according to its schema type 'QName' - 'w3' is an undeclared prefix . Since i am using xsd schema validation .

Comment: May be it needs to addressed at server side than client side.

Answer (score 0):

Understand it is an issue with your application.
May be below script would help you till you get the fix in the application.

Here is how it can be done in soapUI:

- Create a test case
- Add a `groovy script` test step, say step1.
- Add a `soap request` test step, say step2. Have the same request as you currently have which you want to transform.

Below script goes into step1 and it updates the request in step2 as you desired.

**Groovy Script** :  this uses fixed xml.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep

def setRequest = { request ->
    def step = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex+1]
    if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
        step.testRequest.requestContent = request 
        log.info "Request for ${step.name} step is updated"
    }
}

def xml = """<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:w3="http://www.w3.org/">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
    <w3:PerformScan>
        <w3:request>
            <w3:SearchConfiguration>
                <w3:ConfidenceThreshold>?</w3:ConfidenceThreshold>
                <w3:ResultConfiguration></w3:ResultConfiguration>
                <w3:ScanRequest xsi:type="w3:CustomerRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <w3:CustomerId>?</w3:CustomerId>
                    <w3:CustomerName>?</w3:CustomerName>
                </w3:ScanRequest>
            </w3:SearchConfiguration>
        </w3:request>
    </w3:PerformScan>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""
setRequest(groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)))
```

If you want to work with dynamic xml, i.e., **read the request from step2** and set the changed xml back, then use below script instead of above one:

**Groovy Script :**

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep

def getNextStep = { context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex+1] }

def getRequest = { step ->      
        if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
            log.info "Getting request for ${step.name}"
            return step.testRequest.requestContent
        }
        null
}

def setRequest = { step, request ->
    if (step instanceof WsdlTestRequestStep) {
        step.testRequest.requestContent = request 
        log.info "Request for ${step.name} step is updated"
    }
}
def xml = getRequest(getNextStep())
if (xml) {
    setRequest(getNextStep(), groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)))    
}
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5188137487695872)</kbd>